# How to change a UIImageView into landscapemode?

Tags: iphone

How to change a UIImageView into landscapemode?
I have a UIImageview.whe it rotated its still in potrait mode.
code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: where is attach your UIImageView, I mean... are trying to rotate an UIImageView or an UIViewController ?

Comment: I am trying to rotate the UNImageView

Comment: If you created a subclass of an UIImageView, you wont be able to rotate it like that. This method is a delegate method of an UIViewController. Have you added your UIImageView on an UIViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the class/controller that is holding the view and it's inherited classes, it is likely that one of these is set to only allow portrait rotations.

Please check this and then provide us with more information so that we may advise you better, if what I have said is not the case.

Comment: I am trying to rotate the UIImageView.

Comment: I am not getting what you asking .but I try to rotate UIImageview

Answer (score 0):

If you only want your app to run in landscape and NOT allow portrait, update the 'Supported interface orientations' list in your app's info.plist to only include the landscape orientations.