# How to rotate UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change a UIImageView into landscapemode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142859/how-to-change-a-uiimageview-into-landscapemode)

How does one change a `UIImageView` for landscape mode? I have a file UIImageview.whe that, when the device is rotated, is still in potrait mode. Here's my code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```